# How to create an attendance system with django?

Tags: django

Currently i am working a project for making a student management system for my college.
I have a User model and a profile model. I also added an attendance model with User as the foreign key. I was stuck in while i started writing the form for entering the attendance.

```py
class Attendance(models.Model):
    Student = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Hour = models.CharField(max_length=1, blank=False)
    Subject = models.CharField(max_length=8, blank=False)
    Date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    Presence = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=False)
    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.Student}'
```

This is my template where query set is names of Users that should be the default value. The number of Users, the number of forms should come. With this template i can create only one object, with the values of the last form iterated. When the `<form>` is inside `forloop` i get multiple objects with the same values of lastly iterated form.

```
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'academics' %}" style=" padding: 5%">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for query in queryset %}
    <input type="text" name="Student" class="form-control" required id="id_Student" value="{{query}}">
    <input type="text" name="Hour" class="form-control" required id="id_Hour">
    <input type="text" name="Subject" class="form-control" required id="id_Subject">
    <input type="checkbox" name="Presence" required id="id_Presence">
    {% endfor %}
    <button type="Submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

I came to know about formsets, but i don't know how to implement for a complex thing like this. This is my `views.py`:

```py
def academics(request):
    if request.user.is_staff:
        form = forms.AttendanceForm()
        context = {
                    'form': form,
                    'queryset': User.objects.filter(profile__Year='SY',profile__Department='CSE')

                }
        if request.method == "POST" :
            form = forms.AttendanceForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                student = request.POST.get('Student')
                hour = request.POST.get('Hour')
                subject = request.POST.get('Subject')
                boolean = request.POST.get('Presence')
                def bool(boolean):
                    if boolean == 'on':
                        return 'True'
                    else:
                        return 'False'
                form = Attendance(Student=student,Hour=hour,Subject=subject,Presence=bool(boolean))
                form.save()                
        return render(request, 'console/academics.html',context)
    else:
        context = {
            'attends': Attendance.objects.all().exclude(Date=timezone.now()),
            'todays': Attendance.objects.filter(Date=timezone.now())[:8]
        }
        return render(request, 'student/academics.html',context)
```

Can anyone alter the code on how to use formset here. I know am asking an open help instead of asking doubts. Atleast give me hints or correct video tutorial links please!

Comment: That's an unanswered question though. There the user is unable to send values to the database. But i can. Considering the problem, each student-attendance should be a separate form. Then how do i submit multiple forms in a single click?

Comment: Concerning that, i can save the values to the database, but the problem is i can't save n objects with n username and. Please consider reading my question once again. Thanks!